# How do I reduce the size of locale-archive?

Tags: rhel, disk-usage, locale

I have a need to reduce the size of the `locale-archive` file on some of my RHEL6 systems.

Here is that file on my system:

```
[root@-dev-007 locale]# ls -l
total 96800
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 99158704 Sep  9 15:22 locale-archive
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        0 Jun 20  2012 locale-archive.tmpl
```

So I did this ...

```
[root@-dev-007 locale]# localedef --list | grep zh_CN
zh_CN
zh_CN.gb18030
zh_CN.gb2312
zh_CN.gbk
zh_CN.utf8
```

... so I figured I could get rid of `zh_CN` like so ...

```
[root@-dev-007 locale]# localedef --delete-from-archive zh_CN
```

... and I can see `zh_CN` does not get listed anymore like so ...

```
[root@-dev-007 locale]# localedef --list | grep zh_CN
zh_CN.gb18030
zh_CN.gb2312
zh_CN.gbk
zh_CN.utf8
```

... but the size of the `locale-archive` does not get smaller ...

```
[root@-dev-007 locale]# ls -l  
total 96800
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 99158704 Sep  9 17:16 locale-archive
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        0 Jun 20  2012 locale-archive.tmpl
```

... is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can first remove all unneeded locales by doing:

```
$localedef --list-archive | grep -v -i ^en | xargs localedef --delete-from-archive
```

Where `^en` can be replaced by the locale you wish to keep

Then

```
$build-locale-archive
```

If this gives you an error similar to

```
$build-locale-archive
/usr/sbin/build-locale-archive: cannot read archive header
```

Then try this

```
$mv /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl
$build-locale-archive
```

If that still fails, check your version.  According to [this page](https://stephane.lesimple.fr/blog/2010-04-29/fixing-a-locale-archive-breakage.html) newer versions don't have the necessary files to rebuild the archive in order to save space.  You'll need to run

```
yum reinstall glibc-common
```

In later releases of Red Hat Enterprise Linux, you may use `dnf`, a similar application.

Comment: I noticed though that I loss my ssh connection to the host when I execute `build-locale-archive` ... any way of preventing this?

Comment: I'd be careful attempting this. Broke my CentOS server and took me 30 mins to figure out a solution. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246705/i-broke-build-locale-archive-how-do-i-rebuild-it/246708#246708

Comment: dnf in rhel??? Surely you mean yum ;-)

Comment: `build-locale-archive` forces to logout but it seems to work

Answer (score 3):

On Amazon Linux

1. Delete the unused archives from the locale-archive. This command deletes all except the ones beginning with en.

   ```
   localedef --delete-from-archive $(localedef --list-archive | grep -v -i ^en | xargs)
   ```
2. Copy the locale-archive (with removed locales) file to be the new locale-archive.tmpl file

   ```
   cp /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl
   ```
3. Run build-locale-archive

   ```
   build-locale-archive
   ```

**Note:** If you run build-locale-archive it zeros out the .tmpl file after each run and when you run it again you will see the error:

```
build-locale-archive: cannot read archive header
```

You can get a copy of the locale-archive.tmpl file either by copying the current locale-archive to locale-archive.tmpl or by downloading and unpacking glibc-common. If you use the default locale-archive.tmpl file from the glibc-common RPM and run `build-locale-archive` against it, it will create a full (~102MB) locale-archive. You need to repeat the above steps to get the smaller size archive.

In the above case deleting all locales except the en_* ones my locale-archive went from 102MB down to 3.4MB

Answer (score 1):

Mildly easier way,

```
cp /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl
build-locale-archive --install="en"
```

Where "en" is a colon separated list, e.g. "de:en:ja"

I've been trying to find a way to do this to a file not in /usr/lib/locale but so far all attempts fail. Probably need another thread for that problem though.

Comment: i can't comment on the main question. This question is specific to RHEL6 and the solutions work through RHEL8. But in RHEL9 (like Fedora 32+), build-locale-archive is removed and the archive file is 200MB and I haven't yet found a way to reduce it. It is possible it is not needed because there are separate RPM installs for just the english pack, but I don't know that all applications know to reference the individual locales if the locale-archive file is missing.