# Running `build-locale-archive` causes my ssh session to terminate

Tags: rhel, locale

I had previously asked the question, [How do I reduce the size of locale-archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90006/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-locale-archive), and got a great answer to my question, but when I execute `build-locale-archive` I get disconnected from my RHEL6 host.  How can I prevent this?

Update:

I decided to run ...

```
# strace -f -o /tmp/output build-locale-archive
```

... and here's the only interesting output ...

```
17779 truncate("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl", 0) = 0
17779 execve("/usr/sbin/tzdata-update", ["/usr/sbin/tzdata-update"], [/* 0 vars */]) = 0
17779 open("/etc/sysconfig/clock", O_RDONLY) = 3
17779 read(3, "ZONE=\"Africa/Abidjan\"\nUTC=true\n", 32767) = 31
17779 read(3, "", 32736)                = 0
17779 close(3)                          = 0
17779 open("/usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Abidjan", O_RDONLY) = 3
17779 read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0"..., 32768) = 156
17779 read(3, "", 32612)                = 0
17779 close(3)                          = 0
17779 open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)  = 3
17779 read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0"..., 32768) = 156
17779 read(3, "", 32612)                = 0
17779 close(3)                          = 0
17779 open("/var/spool/postfix/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
17779 _exit(0)                          = ?
```

... not sure what to make of that.

Also it looks like `snmpd` and `crond` died when I ran `build-locale-archive`.

Update II:

Thanks for the answer Gilles, but it looks like I may not be following your suggestion correctly as I still loss my connection when I execute:

```
[root@dev-007 ~]# sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
[root@dev-007 ~]# (ulimit -v 100000; build-locale-archive)
build-locale-archive: cannot read archive header
[root@dev-007 ~]# cd /usr/lib/locale/
[root@dev-007 locale]# mv locale-archive locale-archive.tmpl
[root@dev-007 locale]# (ulimit -v 100000; build-locale-archive)
Connection to dev-007 closed.
```

Did I follow your instructions correctly? If not please let me know what I did wrong.

Update III

Sorry I has taken me so long to get back to you all.

Here's my swap info:

```
[root@dev-007 ~]# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition       10178552        0       -1
[root@dev-007 ~]# df /dev/sda3 
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
-                       952296       184    952112   1% /dev
```

Comment: I meant to look into this sooner for you but I couldn't reproduce it on my machine. I did find this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=97520 possibly related link which suggests that the `locale-gen` on Arch can use a lot of RAM.

Comment: Works for me (not with `build-locale-archive`, but with a toy program that allocates a lot of memory). Is there anything in the kernel logs (the OOM killer does leave a log entry)? What does `strace -f -o limited.strace -e bash -c 'ulimit -v 100000; build-locale-archive'` show?

Comment: @RedCricket do you have a swap on your machine?

Answer (score 3):

Given that unrelated processes such as `snmpd` and `crond` are dying, and given [Joel Taylor's observation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90271/running-build-locale-archive-causes-my-ssh-session-to-terminate#comment135642_90271) that [`locale-gen` may use a lot of memory](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=97520), you're a victim of the [OOM killer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory).

To avoid OOM kills, set the overcommit policy to [disable overcommitting](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt): `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2`

Even if you disable overcommitting, it would be better to confine the damage to `locale-gen` by limiting how much memory it can allocate.

```
(ulimit -v 100000; build-locale-archive)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer Gilles, but I couldn't get it to work.  Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the truncation of the locale file.
Check: http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/forum/linux-fedora-core-15-usrliblocalelocale-archive-still-large-after-removing-all-one-locale

So, if you just copy the locale file over the template file and run build-locale-archive, everything works:

`cp -f /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl
build-locale-archive.`