# I broke build-locale-archive how do I rebuild it?

Tags: locale, system-recovery

I used the top answer here [How do I reduce the size of locale-archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90006/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-locale-archive) because I wanted to free up a little space.

Now my web server is down and I can't get build-locale-archive working.

First error I get it is `build-locale-archive: cannot read archive header`

When I copy the locale file from my other server I get this...

`build-locale-archive: incomplete set of locale files in "/usr/lib/locale/tmp`

And then build-local-archive brings my file to zero file size:

`root root        0 Dec  1 22:03 locale-archive.tmpl`

That /tmp directory is from some instructions I found in Google to recover from this error by downloading glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64.rpm, but apparently I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

This gave me the idea to just reinstall glibc-common http://hpc.mtech.edu/scyld-doc/administration-guide/x3137.html

`yum reinstall glibc-common`

That didn't work, but then I was confident I had the right "goodies" and it was just my tinkering that was the issue.

build-locale-archive still choked on the temporary directory that I had, so I just did `rm -rf /usr/lib/locale/tmp` and then `build-locale-archive` worked.

Then I restarted nginx and mysql, but I was still offline. I had to reboot the system. Then it worked.